# iron-scroll-threshold in custom element

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

In my `index.html` I have a `paper-scroll-header-panel` with a `paper-toolbar` and a custom element serving as the page content:

```
<body unresolved>
    <template is="dom-bind" id="app">
        <paper-scroll-header-panel>
            <paper-toolbar class="medium-tall">
                ...
            </paper-toolbar>

            <!-- Main Content -->
            <div class="content">
                <x-content></x-content>
            </div>
        </paper-scroll-header-panel>
    </template>
</body>
```

In `x-content`, I have a `firebase-collection` which I am looping over to show data:

```
<dom-module id="x-content">
    <template>
        <firebase-collection
            limit-to-first="30"
            location="myFirebaseURL"
            data="{{items}}"></firebase-collection>

        <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{items}}">
            <x-item item="{{item}}"></x-item>
        </template>
    </template>
    <script>
        Polymer({
            is: "x-content",
            _loadMoreData: function (e) {
                // load more
            }
        });
    </script>
</dom-module>
```

I want to be able to load more data when the user scrolls. I have tried implementing the `iron-scroll-threshold` but it is not working. I expect I need to use the `scrollTarget` attribute to link it to an element which will fire the scroll event but I'm not sure which element I should use.

I have tried setting it to `body`, `document` and the `paper-scroll-header-panel` but none of these are working when I scroll - some are even firing on page load when no scrolling is happening!

Has anyone tried this?

Comment: Hi Ben,

Did you a find a solution to this problem? We are facing the same issue. Might this have something to do with declaring scope in some way?

Thanks

Comment: No not yet. I will try again and see if I can sort it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to link to `paperScrollHeaderPanel.scroller`
and make sure when loading the data function to clear the triggers:

```
scrollThreshold.clearTriggers();
```

[see this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/polymer-dev/tzgVpM2sTIM)

Comment: Thanks for that. Annoyingly, I probably can't use this with firebase as the idea was to change the `limitToFirst` property of the `firebase-collection`. That was until I realised that it initialises a new query rather than tacking on more to the end.

Comment: I've got the threshold working, but I have 2 listings on 2 separate iron-pages, they are both targeted on the headerPanel, but one threshold is triggering both lists. How can I prevent this?

Comment: Daantje, you can use this [app-scrollpos-control](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/app-layout?active=app-scrollpos-control)